# @IBInspectable: wrong bounds and frames at runtime when I add subviews

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, ibinspectable

This is my `@IBInspectable:` code:

```
@IBDesignable
class PBOView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var borderRightColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            let borderRightView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(frame.size.width - 10, 0, 10, frame.size.height))
            borderRightView.backgroundColor = borderRightColor

            addSubview(borderRightView)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result in Storyboard:

*the width of UIView are `150`*
[image]

and in iPhone Simulator:
*the width of UIView are `150`, but should be `80`* since it is iPhone. **This is why the rectangles are not visible inside my custom views**
[image]

When I set `clearColor` to the background of my views, the result is following:
[image]

**Why there are a wrong bounds' and frames' width for that UIViews?**  Actually they are a width from Storyboard instead of a **real** widths at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I was digging some, but I haven't found **elegant property or method** to solve this problem. The only way so far is:

```
@IBDesignable
class PBOView: UIView {

    var borderRightView: UIView?

    @IBInspectable var borderRightColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            addBorderRightView()
        }
    }

    func addBorderRightView() {

        borderRightView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(frame.size.width - 10, 0, 10, frame.size.height))
        borderRightView!.backgroundColor = borderRightColor
        addSubview(borderRightView!)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if let borderRightView = borderRightView {
            borderRightView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        if let borderRightColor = borderRightColor {
            addBorderRightView()
        }
    }
}
```

Just override `layoutSubviews()` method with your own content. Since `layoutSubviews()` is called almost everywhere it is working as it should.

The result is:

[image]

Still looking for **elegant** solution - method that do this for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
The subView's frame should be equal to the placeHolder's bounds.
i.e

```
subView.frame = placeholder.bounds;
```